# cupcakes keep on sinking in center

Tags: cupcakes

I'm trying to make vanilla cupcakes from scratch and the center is always sinking in and when I touch them they're soft like they're under-cooked?

Maybe it's the all-purpose flour that I'm using? I have no idea..

Comment: what was the recipe, maybe we can work out what ingredient you need more of or are lacking?

Comment: Please give the recipe **and** method, it's impossible to tell from what is in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oven temperature gauges are wildly inaccurate.  So it is very likely your times and temperatures are off.   It sounds like the cupcakes are under-cooked, and are sinking as they cool. Use a good digital thermometer to test the internal temperature of your cupcakes.  Shoot for 205 - 209F (96-98C) internal, at the center of the cupcake.  Alternately, you can use the low tech. method of testing them with a toothpick by dipping into the center.  If it comes out clean, they are done.  If there is batter sticking to the toothpick, keep baking.  ...and it doesn't hurt to have a good oven thermometer to see where your oven stands in terms of accuracy.